# What are the different Ubuntu Kernel git tags for?

Tags: kernel

Going through the Ubuntu Kernel git source there are several tags, the meaning of which I'm uncertain of.

How can I find out which tag is the one currently in the repos for each version of Ubuntu? Is it *okay* to compile the latest tagged versions of the kernel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In each Ubuntu Kernel Team git repository the Ubuntu-* tags represent the git commit which was used to build the official source package for any particular upload.  For instance in the ubuntu-precice git the tag Ubuntu-3.2.0-23.36 represents the 3.2.0-23.36 source upload.  Some tags have an additional -lts- component indicating they are the official LTS backport for the containing release, in the ubuntu-lucid git repository the tag Ubuntu-lts-3.0.0-18.31 represents the 3.0.0-18.31 oneiric LTS backport for lucid.

You can use the Launchpad versions page for the linux package to determine the current versions uploaded into each pocket of each release:

```
https://www.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux
```

All recent tags should be signed by the committer to prevent modification.  You should be safe to build any official tag and expect to get a substantially similar result to the uploaded binary packages for that release.